# How to install Ubuntu using CLI commands from a live CD?

Tags: live-cd, installation, text

I was wondering if there is any way of installing Ubuntu from command line using the Ubuntu Live CD.
I am aware of the alternate CD text install, but just wanted to know if its possible to do so from the Live CD installer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu manually from command line (without installer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724179/installing-ubuntu-manually-from-command-line-without-installer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an easy solution by far, but you can use debootstrap:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/amd64/linux-upgrade.html

Comment: The link is no more working… Even https://archive.org/ does not help here.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [text-based alternate install CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)....then the installation is in text mode. Or try to change the start options.

Comment: change start option? in a live cd? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can change startup parameters in grub @Ubuntuser

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an alternate text-based CD to access command line- you can use key combination Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to TTY1.