# Installing Ubuntu manually from command line (without installer)

Tags: system-installation, debootstrap

Some Linux distributions is lack of installation script, like Gentoo or Arch. Everything can be done by hand (partitioning disk, making filesystems, installing, etc). The questions is:

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in that way?

I'm making some tests with Ubuntu and I want to install Ubuntu Server in mounted disk image file. But installer can't skip disk partition step.

Comment: Use the normal Arch installation procedure, but instead of `pacstrap`, use `debootstrap`: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `debootstrap` I can install system in image file with command:

```
debootstrap --arch i386 trusty /mnt/imagefile/ http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

thx @muru

Comment: Is the 64 bit `--arch` option `amd64`? The man page doesn't say if it is x86-64 or amd64 or something else. Is `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` still a valid URL for the SCRIPT (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/debootstrap.8.html)?

Comment: @MountainX See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489203/4196 which points to this: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/